# Выполнить действие и убить все потоки

Tags: java, многопоточность

Не могу сообразить, как соорудить следующую вещь.

```
private volatile ComponentEvent ce;

public void go(JFrame thisFrame, String string, ImageIcon icon) {

    thisFrame.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {

            System.out.println("componentResized");

            ce = e;

            Thread myThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    changePosition(e);
                }
            });
            myThread.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) {

            System.out.println("componentMoved");

            ce = e;

            Thread myThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    changePosition(e);
                }
            });
            myThread.start();
        }
    });

}

private synchronized void changePosition(ComponentEvent e) {

    try {
        Thread.sleep(10);
    } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println(ce.getComponent().getX() + " " + ce.getComponent().getY());
}
```

И результат в консоли при componentMoved/componentResized:
componentMoved
componentMoved
componentMoved
186 189
componentMoved
componentMoved
183 186
183 186
183 186
**183 186**
Можно ли как ни будь сделать что бы после `Thread.sleep(10)` метод `sysout` выполнился только 1 раз с текущими реальными данными, а все потоки которые я создал(`myThread.start()`), кроме того что сейчас юзает `changePosition`, были убиты?
Короче, мне нужно пересчитывать много чего в зависимости от положения окна и его размеров, не хочу обсчитывать это стопицот раз, если достаточно 1-го.

Comment: как вариант в каждом потоке сохранить актуальные координаты на момент его выполнения, а вывод делать только тому потоку, у которого координаты соответствуют координатам в ce.. убивать нет смысла, они сами остановятся

Comment: @keekkenen да, как я сам не додумался... напишите ответ, пожалуйста, я приму.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public class Test {
        private volatile int count = 0; //изменяемый компонент

        public Test() {
            // три эмуляции движения
            new MyThread().start();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(300);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            new MyThread().start();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(300);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            new MyThread().start();
        }

        public static void main(String[] s) {
            new Test();
        }

        private synchronized void waiting(int value) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (count == value) { // вывод актуального состояния
                System.out.println("last: " + count);
            }
        }

        private class MyThread extends Thread {
            private int value;

            public void run() {
                count++; // изменение компонента при движении
                value = count; // состояние после изменения
                System.out.println("moved to " + count);
                waiting(value);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: адаптируешь идею под свои условия